# Using MS Unity DI Container and WPF in a layered Application

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am new in .Net Technologies and i wanted to start with a layered application as a test for Unity and WPF. When execute i get the folowing exception : ConfigurationErrorsException : 
No valid attributes were found to construct the value for the parameter mefRepository 
Please check the configuration file. Below The Unity Configuration :

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
<typeAliases>
<typeAlias alias="IUnitOfWork"   type="DDDTest.Domain.Core.IUnitOfWork,DDDTest.Domain.Core"/>
  <typeAlias alias="UnitOfWork"     type="DDDTest.Infrastructure.Data.MainModule.UnitOfWork,DDDTest.Infrastructure.Data.MainModule"/>
  <typeAlias alias="IRepository"    type="DDDTest.Domain.Core.IRepository,DDDTest.Domain.Core"/>
  <typeAlias alias="Repository"     type="DDDTest.Infrastructure.Data.MainModule.Repository,DDDTest.Infrastructure.Data.MainModule"/>
  <typeAlias alias="IMefRepository" type="DDDTest.Domain.MainModule.Entities.IMefRepository,DDDTest.Domain.MainModule.Entities"/>
  <typeAlias alias="MefRepository"  type="DDDTest.Infrastructure.Data.MainModule.Repositories.MefRepository,DDDTest.Infrastructure.Data.MainModule.Repositories"/>
  <typeAlias alias="IMefService"    type="DDDTest.Domain.MainModule.Services.IMefService,DDDTest.Domain.MainModule.Services"/>
  <typeAlias alias="MefService"     type="DDDTest.Domain.MainModule.Services.MefService,DDDTest.Domain.MainModule.Services"/>
  </typeAliases>
  <container>
  <register type ="IUnitOfWork"     mapTo="UnitOfWork" name="UoW"/>
  <register type="IRepository"      mapTo="Repository">
    <constructor>
      <param name="uow" dependencyName="UoW"/>
    </constructor>
  </register>
  <register type ="IMefRepository"  mapTo="MefRepository" name="MefRepo"/>
  <register type ="IMefService"     mapTo="MefService">
    <constructor>
      <param name="mefRepository" dependenceyName="MefRepo"/>
      <param name="mefRepository" dependenceyType="MefRepository"/>
      </constructor>
      </register>
      </container>
  </unity>
```

And MefService class is as follows :

```
namespace DDDTest.Domain.MainModule.Services
{
public class MefService : IMefService, IDisposable
{
    IMefRepository _mefRepo;

    public MefService(IMefRepository mefRepository)
    {
        _mefRepo = mefRepository;

    }


    //Add New Mef
    public void AddMef(misfor _mef)
    {
        _mefRepo.Add(_mef);
    }

    //Delete a mef
    public void DeleteMef(misfor _mef)
    {
        _mefRepo.Remove(_mef);
    }

    //Get a new empty mef
    public misfor GetNewObject()
    {
        return _mefRepo.GetNewEmpty();
    }

    //Find Mef By Primary Key
    public misfor GetById(string ctr, short mef)
    {
        return _mefRepo.GetById(ctr, mef);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _mefRepo = null;
    }

}
```

}

and WPF window is as follows :

```
namespace DDDTest.Presentation.MainModule
{
/// <summary>
/// Logique d'interaction pour MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    IMefRepository _mr;
    MefService _ms;
    misfor _currentMef;

    public IUnityContainer unityContainer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    //Initialisation du container unity pour l'injection des dépendances
    public void InitIocContainer()
    {
        unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
        unityContainer.LoadConfiguration();

    }



     private void MefCode_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
     {
         string  c = txctrCode.Text;
         short   m = short.Parse(txMefCode.Text);

         if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
         {

             _currentMef = _ms.GetById(c, m);
                 if (_currentMef != null)
                     grdMaster.DataContext = _currentMef;
                 else
                     MessageBox.Show("Mise en force introuvable.", "Erreur", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

         }

     }



    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InitIocContainer();

        _ms = new MefService(_mr);

        _currentMef = _ms.GetNewObject();
        grdMaster.DataContext = _currentMef;

    }
   }
  }
```

The first problem is that i do not know where to initialize The Unity Container. i found many samples in the Net but all about Unity and WPF/MVVM pattern.
The second problem that i can't locate the origin of error, because the code of MefService class seems correct.
Your help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would initialize the container at application startup.

In terms of the error you are seeing the following does not look correct:

```
<register type ="IMefService"     mapTo="MefService">
  <constructor>
    <param name="mefRepository" dependenceyName="MefRepo"/>
    <param name="mefRepository" dependenceyType="MefRepository"/>
  </constructor>
</register>
```

dependenceyName and dependenceyType are not valid attribute names due to the spelling typos.  Also, it seems wrong to have two parameters with the same name.